# Ubuntu Server continues to want to upgrade after already fully upgrading

Tags: server, upgrade, ssh, 13.04

I upgraded my servers from 12.10 to 13.04 via SSH session.
All upgrades for each box were successful except for one, which failed to boot after rebooting (faulty harddrive it turns out).
After replacing the hdd, i did a fresh install of 13.04.

here is my log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5602791/

Please note that box0 is a fresh install of 13.04 and it does NOT ask me to upgrade my OS everytime i log in.

Now note that box1 is an upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 and it continues to ask me to upgrade everytime i log in; see lines 32 and 33.

Why does it do this, and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upgrade notification is cached and isn't removed after the upgrade for some reason. You have to manually remove the cached message to force Ubuntu to recheck if you need an upgrade.

Removed the notification cache with this command and you should be set:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
```

The script that checks for release upgrades is located at /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd, you can read it for more detail.