# Release upgrade notification after upgrade completed

Tags: server, upgrade, apt, 13.04, notification

I've upgraded my ubuntu server to the 13.04 release. Unfortunately during the upgrade process I lost the connection to the server and the server hasn't completed correctly the upgrade to this release.

The problem happened during the upgrade of the installed software and I've fixed the problems related to apt-get upgrade running a shell suggested command to fix the problem and complete the upgrade of the system.

The only problem that seems that I still have is the notification of an available release upgrade to version 13.04 that appear each time I login, but my ubuntu says that's already at 13.04 as in displayed in this screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix it? Could I consider the upgraded process completed safely?

Comment: As future advice, run these things in a `screen` session. Also allows for easy saving of whole output to log.

Answer (score 2):

Your upgrade probably went fine. I got the same problem with the upgrade notification not going away after a successful upgrade too and found out that you have to manually delete the notification.

I posted this response in another question: https://askubuntu.com/a/293730/157588

> The upgrade notification is cached and isn't removed after the upgrade for some reason. You have to manually remove the cached message to force Ubuntu to recheck if you need an upgrade.
>
> Removed the notification cache with this command and you should be set:
>
> > sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
>
> The script that checks for release upgrades is located at /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd, you can read it for more detail.